# Set max width of a Gtk::TextView

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I've created a textview which is being filled by a Gtk::TextBuffer, however the buffer contains a lot of characters and the window gets wider than the width of the screen.

Is there a way to define a max width for a Gtk::TextView?

Comment: TextView or TreeView?

Comment: TextView, I've edited the typo, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the text view in a `Gtk::ScrolledWindow` and set the size request of the scrolled window.

Comment: I using `gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS)` and `gtk_widget_set_size_request (scrolled_window, -1, 100)`. Checked with GTK 2.24, GTK 3.0-3.24.